# How to write recursive and optimal solution for decoding the compressed string?

Tags: ruby

I found a problem statement over the internet, was trying to solve it in ruby.

Input and output are self explanatory.

Eg. 1, Input : `2[abc]3[ab]c`

Output : `abcabcabcababababc`

Explanation : `2` times `abc` and `3` times `ab` and then `c`

Eg. 2
Input : `2[3[a]b]`

Output : `aaabaaab`

I tried this,
But it doesn't work for multiple level.

```
num = 1
str = ""
"3[abc]4[ab]2[3[a]b]c".each_char do |ch|
  if ch.to_i != 0
    num = ch
  elsif ch == "["
    next
  elsif ch == "]"
    num.to_i.times { print str }
    str = ""
    num = 1
  else
    str << ch
  end
end
```

I was looking for recursive call.

Comment: _"I was looking for recursive call"_ – you usually start with something that you can _call_ like a method or proc.

Comment: I tried but was unable to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "2[abc]3[ab]c2[de]fg"
```

```
str.gsub(/(\d+)\[(\p{L}+)\]/) { $2*$1.to_i }  
  #=> "abcabcabababcdedefg"
  #    ^^^^^^
  #          ^^^^^^
  #                 ^^^^
```

We can write the regular expression in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting.

```
/
(\d+)     # match one or more digits, save to capture group 1 
\[        # match '[' 
(\p{L}+)  # match one or more letters, save to capture group 2
\]        # match ']'
/x        # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

For the first match,

```
$1 #=> "2"
$2 #=> "abc"
```

so the block becomes

```
"abc"*2
  #=> "abcabc"
```